# node javascript set variables in a plugin that will be used whenever the plugin is required

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a plugin that I can set variables for, so that when the plugin is required the variables within the plugin are already set.

ie.
*index.js*

```
var plugin = require('plugin');
plugin.setPluginValue('AwesomeValue');
```

*anotherPage.js*

```
var plugin = require('plugin');
alert(plugin.getPluginValue())
```

->`AwesomeValue`

When I try to do this, I only get partial functionality. For example, if I'm using the plugin for a webpage, and I go to a page where the value is set, and then called, everything works. But if I try going to another page without setting the value, I would get undefined.

EDIT Example Code

```
var pluginValue
export function setPluginValue(newPluginValue){
 pluginValue = newPluginValue;
}
export function getPluginValue(){
 return pluginValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the plugin?

Comment: That's very basic, but too long for a comment. Long story short, think about where the values you set exist... (Or as an analogy, if you write your name on a word document, then close it, then open an excel sheet - would you expect your name to be there??)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a default value for you plugin set it in the plugin code:

```
var pluginValue = 'DefaultValue'
export function setPluginValue(newPluginValue){
 pluginValue = newPluginValue;
}
export function getPluginValue(){
 return pluginValue;
}
```